# Install PHP SDK for Couchbase server

Tags: php, couchbase

I try to use PHP SDK for Couchbase server.

I use OS Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.2

First, I install following this  [tutorial](https://docs.couchbase.com/php-sdk/2.6/start-using-sdk.html). The output is

[image]

Then I insert line extension=couchbase to file with path (/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini)

[image]

Finally, I restart apache2 service. But when I check phpinfo, it no have Couchbase module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction you are referring to does not ask to install PCS extension. But it does say that couchbase extension depends on JSON module, and it have to be loaded before couchbase. So you have to make sure that `extension=couchbase` goes after `extension=json`. Also make sure that libcouchbase.dll is in the PATH (for instance if you are using CLI SAPI `php.exe`, it have to be in the same directory as the binary).

The second point is that on your screenshot, you are showing CLI `php.ini`. Make sure that your `apache2` binary is using this particular configuration.